# Как сделать картинку сбоку текста

Tags: css3, html5

```css
.section__info-items{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    

}
.section__info-item{
 width: 33.3333%;
text-align: center;
}


.section__info-item + .section__info-item{
margin-left: 4%;    
}

.section__head{
color: #242121;
font-family: Roboto Condensed;
font-size: 24px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 28px; /* 116.667% */
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
padding-bottom: 33px;
}


.section__info-text{
color: #242121;
font-family: Roboto Condensed;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 18px; /* 128.571% */
letter-spacing: 0.6px;  

}

.section__head-info{
color: #242121;
font-family: Roboto Condensed;
font-size: 24px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 28px; /* 116.667% */
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
padding-bottom: 10px;

}

.info__icon{
float: left;

}
```

```html
<section class="section-two">
<div class="container">
<h2 class="section__info-title">В  ШКОЛЕ ВЫ ПОЛУЧИТЕ <span>/</span></h2>

<div class="section__info-items">
  <div class="section__info-item">
<img class="info__icon" src="image/icon__bg-1.svg" alt="">  
    <h4 class="section__head">ПРОЖИВАНИЕ</h4>

<p class="section__info-text" style="text-align: left;">Наша школа серфинга находится в 100 м от океанского побережья. К услугам гостей открытый бассейн и бесплатный Wi-Fi. Из верхней террасы открывается вид на океан. Расстояние до центра города 15 мин. </p>
</div>

<div class="section__info-item">
   <img class="info__icon" src="image/icon__bg-2.svg" alt="">  
  <h4 class="section__head-info" >ПЕРЕЛЕТ И <br>
    СТРАХОВКУ</h4>
 
  <p class="section__info-text" style="text-align: left;">Все участники программы застрахованы страховой компанией Allianz.
    Перелет из Тенерифе до острова Лансароте  и обратно входит в стоимость программы</p>
  </div>
  

  <div class="section__info-item">
    <img class="info__icon" src="image/icon__bg-3.svg" alt="">
    <h4 class="section__head-info">ОБУЧЕНИЕ И <br>
      ЭКИПИРОВКУ</h4>
  
    <p class="section__info-text" style="text-align: left;">Все оборудование и экипировка известных производителей и предоставляется на весь курс программы. Тренировочный процесс начинается с определения вашего уровня катания </p>
    </div>
    
</div>


</div>


</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.leftimg {
  float: left;
  /* Выравнивание по левому краю */
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 0;
  /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
}

.rightimg {
  float: right;
  /* Выравнивание по правому краю  */
  margin: 7px 0 7px 7px;
  /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
}
```

```html
<p><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" width="132" height="174" class="leftimg"> тут какой-то текст </p>
<h2>Пресс-релиз аналитической группы</h2>
<p><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" class="rightimg">тут какой-то текст</p>
```

Comment: `float: left` для такого уже давным-давно не используют)

Comment: Да я знаю уже но другой вариант должен быть замене этому